# Import.io - URL Pattern for "where to extract data from" optimization

Tags: regex, web-crawler, import.io

When crawling with Import.io, we have the advanced option to set an URL Pattern to determine with pages should have data extracted.

I'm used to use Regex, so I'm having a hard time to use the Import.io URL Patterns.

The pattern in Regex would be

http://www.site.com/.*[0-9]+.html.*

**How to do that with the Import.io Pattern?**

I'd tried the following but it didn't work:

www.site.com/{any}{num}.html

Some examples that should be extracted:

- www.site.com/foo/bar/foo234.html
- www.site.com/bla890.html
- www.site.com/bar/bar/bar/bar/bar/bar/aaa123.html

These are the Import.io Notation:

- {any} ﻿- anything (including nothing) ﻿{num} ﻿- a number, e.g. 8767
- ﻿{alpha} ﻿- a-z characters, e.g. Dog ﻿{alpha-num} ﻿- either alpha or
  num, e.g. 435h5k ﻿
- {words-num} ﻿- words containing numbers separated
  by -, _ or +, e.g. this-is_a+2nd example ﻿
- {not-slash} ﻿- anything
  apart from a slash ﻿
- {uuid} ﻿- a UUID, e.g.
  439a110f-bba1-46a5-befd-1f32cfb63dc8 ﻿
- {query-string} ﻿- a query
  string, e.g. ?a=1&b=2%c=3
- ﻿{query-params} ﻿- a partial query string,
  e.g. a=1&b=2 ﻿
- {ref} ﻿- a reference, otherwise known as an anchor,
  e.g. #foo ﻿$ ﻿- match the end of the URL

More details: http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/247574-advanced-crawler-options

Thanks!